# Yii - urlmanager and active highlighting menus

Tags: yii

I've just figured out how to configure the urlmanager rules to work with rules such as

```
'urlManager'=>array(
'urlFormat'=>'path',
'showScriptName'=>false,
'rules'=>array(
        '<type:\w+>s'=>'article/index',
)
```

however, now my CMenu does not have active highlighting for my main menu with link

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
'items'=>array(
    array('label'=>'Articles', 'url'=>array('/articles')),

)); ?>
```

Can this active highlighting still work even though I want my URLs to look like '/articles'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution, seems kinda gross though. All I did was add an 'active' criteria to check if the current URI has '/article' as the front.

```
array('label'=>'Articles', 
    'url'=>array('/articles'), 
    'active'=>strpos(Yii::app()->request->requestUri, '/article')===0),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array('label'=>'Articles', 
'url'=>array('/articles'), 
'active'=>Yii::app()->controller->name == 'articles'),
```